# SQL Server : how to define header?

Tags: sql-server

I have an issue about header

Example :

```
A       B   C   D
-------------------
1000    35  M   15
1001    43  M   14
1002    24  F   16
```

Let's call it `main_table`. I want to define the header title into :

```
EmployeeID  Age Sex Hour_Rate
------------------------------
1000        35  M   15
1001        43  M   14
1002        24  F   16
```

So, I need to create something to define header **code** into readable text.

```
A = EmployeeID
B = Age
C = Sex
D = Hour_Rate
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Query with an alias? `select A as [EmployeeID], B as [Age], C as ...` or are you asking to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple alias for that :

```
select A as EmployeeID,
       B as Age,
       C as Sex,
       D as HourRate
from   main_table
```

To make life easier you could create a view for this :

```
create view vwMain_table as
select A as EmployeeID,
       B as Age,
       C as Sex,
       D as HourRate
from   main_table
```

now when you do

```
select * from vwMain_table
```

you will get this :

```
EmployeeID  Age Sex Hour_Rate
1000        35  M   15
1001        43  M   14
1002        24  F   16
```

Comment: Of course !!! as simple as that !!! how can I not have a thought about it. Thanks a lot @GuidoG